# React filter object and change value within child object

Tags: reactjs, object, filter

I am trying to use `filter` to make my life easier.

My goal:  Change the `closeTime.hours` of `filter openDay(TUESDAY)`

I have an array of objects that looks like:

```
buildHours = [
  {
    "openDay": "MONDAY",
    "openTime": {},
    "closeDay": "MONDAY",
    "closeTime": {
      "hours": 24
    }
  },
  {
    "openDay": "TUESDAY",
    "openTime": {
      "hours": 9
    },
    "closeDay": "TUESDAY",
    "closeTime": {
      "hours": 17
    }
  },
]
```

How I am doing this right now is removing the "Tuesday" Object using

```
    const tempObject = buildHours.filter(i => i.openDay !== "TUESDAY"); // Destroy Tues
    const tempHours = buildHours.filter(i => i.openDay === "TUESDAY")[0]; // Save Tues Obj
    tempHours.openTime.hours = e.value; // Change Hour
    tempObject.push(tempHours); // Recombine
    console.log(tempObject);
```

Then "rebuilding" the "TUESDAY" object and adding it back to the main object.  Although it works .. It seems a little convoluted. Isn't there a way I can use a combination of `filter()` and set `closeTime.hours = 17`?  I have tried 6 ways to Sunday and nothing seems to work.

Is the way I am doing it right now the preferred method?  Remove the object, rebuild and combine?

Or is there a more elegant way to change the hours for Tuesday without destroying the object and rebuilding it in the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the rest of the context, it's hard to say what the "best" way to do this would be... but, generally, I'd use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of `filter`; something like:

```js
const buildHours = [ /* ... */ ];  // no change to this

const handleHourChange = (e) => {
  return buildHours.map(o => {
    if (o.openDay !== 'TUESDAY') return o;

    return {
      ...o,
      openTime: {
        ...o.openTime,
        hours: e.value,
      },
    };
  };
});
```

Also - one minor point on your code - instead of using `filter` to find the `Tuesday` object, you can use `find` -

```js
const tempHours = buildHours.find(i => i.openDay === "TUESDAY");
```

And even if you *did* want to use `filter` and just get the first one, you can use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const [tempHours] = buildHours.filter(i => i.openDay === "TUESDAY");
```